# Align control to a path in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

kann I place align a control (in this case a button) on a path in Xaml?
And as the path moves the control is aligned to it. Basically the same concept like a motionpath in animation but without an animation. Just have a button in the middle of a path...
I would be great to no write a custom control for that.
Any Ideas?